# Changing windows manager without a windows manager

Tags: recovery-mode, i3-wm, openbox

I honestly don't know how to phrase my problem differently (Question title's awful, sorry!)... Just in case this is important, I'm using Lubuntu LTS 18.04. Here's what happened:

I wanted to change my windows manager: from openbox to i3. (I've never done this before.) What I did was `sudo apt install i3` and (see the picture below) changed openbox to i3.

[image: Changed openbox to i3]

After this, I rebooted my machine and i3 loaded. The *what should your mod key be?* prompt appeared and disappeared a couple of seconds after. After a couple of reboots later, I managed to assign my Windows Key as the Mod Key just before the panel disappeared. Then I tried to open Firefox through the dmenu but it didn't work: the prompt *Firefox isn't your default browser* appeared and disappeared a couple of seconds after. Firefox never ran. Tried to open a terminal and this time nothing happened. Tried to exit i3 unsuccessfully (nothing happened). And practically, I can't do anything there! Can't exit i3, can't open a terminal, can't open a browser...

I tried booting in recovery mode and using the terminal there as root but, I don't know if this makes sense, I think there are a lot of limitations there. I couldn't do anything with openbox there. The command `openbox --replace` didn't work: **Failed to open the display from the DISPLAY enviroment variable** error. I could only uninstall openbox there through `apt`'s `purge` but couldn't install it again (some other error which I don't know if is important or not)!

How can I recover my Lubuntu machine?

Thanks!

Comment: When you boot, do you still get to the login screen? If so, simply change to Openbox. See this image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7E1q.png

Comment: Nope. No login screen.

Comment: It turns out I could login through `ctrl+alt+F2` and I finally got access to the terminal! I'm sorry I haven't posted my solution... !